# Error with OutParameter in custom Action

Tags: dynamics-crm

There is the error:
*The type OutArgument`1 of the property Result is not supported.* 
And there is the code

```
 [Output("Result")]
  public OutArgument<EntityCollection> Result { get; set; }
```

I get this error when I try to update my assembly.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use type `EntityCollection` in generic `OutArgument<T>` properties.

Supported types are:

- Boolean
- DateTime
- Decimal
- Double
- EntityReference
- Int32
- Money
- OptionSetValue
- String

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx).

Comment: But web GUI allows me to assing EntityCollection type to OutParameter. Or this is just misleading from Microsoft?

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy: I have no experience with web GUI. Can it be it simply accepts any type?